# import components with ~ instead of './'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, webpack

In my pages/screens folder, I made an index file and did something like this:

```
export * from './UserPage';
export * from './users/SearchPage';
```

So now, when I want to import components from these pages in my App.tsx file, I can just

```
import { SearchPage, NewPage } from './pages';
```

instead of typing the full relative path. However, I want to use something like

```
import { SearchPage, NewPage } from '~/pages';
```

For this, I added this into my `tsconfig.json` file as it seemed to work in another project but it's not working for me here:

```
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"],
      "~": ["./"]
    },
```

How else can I change my import format?

Edit:
tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@modules/*": ["modules/*"],
      "@config/*": ["config/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["shared/*"]
    },
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why would you have package files in your home directory? Why would you want to expose the contents of your home directory to HTTP requests? Does your webserver run under your personal user? This is a really odd thing to want to do...

Comment: this is very much not an odd thing to want to do. tilde is often used in import paths as a shorthand for the project root (or root source dir).

Answer (score 0):

Double check what the value of `baseUrl` is in your tsconfig.json.

Any module you load that matches those paths will be loaded relative to the `baseUrl`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

Comment: Turns out I wasn't using a baseUrl earlier. I added it into my tsconfig, along with paths. Now idk how/where to specify ```~```? Now If I import a file in App.tsx, I can do it like this ```import { HomePage } from 'pages';``` but not with the ```~``` Please see my file in the updated qs.

Answer (score 0):

You can define at your `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "paths": {
      "@modules/*": ["modules/*"],
      "@config/*": ["config/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["shared/*"]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

Into you `tsconfig.json` at the `paths`, you can do something like

```
"paths": {
    "@pages/*": ["pages"],
}
```

But you will need to use `import {...} from '@pages'`;

Comment: Would you like use `import { HomePage } from 'pages'`?

Comment: I am already doing that. I want to do something like import from '~/pages'

Comment: So do you want to import all components from pages? Like `import {HomePage, Home, SignUp } from '~/pages'`?

Comment: Pages from ```'~/pages'```, components from ```'~/components'``` etc. All these folders are inside src. Right now, I can import from ```'./pages``` and ```'./components'```

Comment: I guess that using the `@` format is better. But if you want, try this
`"paths": {  "~/*": ["./src/*"], "~": ["./"] },`

Comment: I tried this but I can still only do this: ```import { HomePage } from 'pages'``` and not with ```~/pages```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222319/discussion-between-vagner-wentz-and-jnl).

Answer (score 0):

As of the fact that you use webpack with typescript you need to inform webpack that you are using the paths feature.

You can do it by using [tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin)